# Illustrator CC Paste In Front

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am unable to use the "paste in front" function. It does not matter if I use the keyboard command or go to edit>paste in front. No matter what I do, it pastes the object in its original location. I have tried to change between Global and Artboard rulers as per a previous suggestion but it did not help. I have read a ton of similar posts but none of the suggestions have worked.

I am getting very frustrated as I've used this function many times in the past and never had an issues until today and this issue is stalling a big project. Anyone have

Comment: Could it be that what ever is in front, is on a different layer above the one you're trying to paste.

Comment: Are you just copying something then pasting in front? That will just put a duplicate *exactly* on top of the original.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a number of things:

1. Your drawing mode is set to Draw Behind. Check your tools panel to see if you see the following:

[image: Tools panel set to Draw Behind]

If you do, click the first option or press Shift-D until your mode changes to Draw Normal. If your tools panel is in one-column mode, the Shift-D command will still work, or look for the drawing mode at the bottom (you will only see one icon instead of all three).

2. You are copying from a different layer and "Paste Remembers Layers" is checked. Look in your layers panel flyout menu and uncheck that option. The flyout menu is here:

[image: Layers panel flyout menu]

3. You are copying and pasting onto a layer that is lower in the layer stack than the object you want to paste in front of. In the following example, if I try to cut the rectangle on layer 1 and paste in front on layer 1 or 2, it will still appear behind the ellipse.

[image: Example with ellipse and rectangle with three layers]